# How can I create a child group in SSRS Report Builder that is a row, not a column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

I am trying to create child group that becomes a row under its parent group. But it automatically creates it as a column to the right. I want it as a row. Here is a screenshot of what I want to mimic:

#### End Goal

[image: End Goal]

Here is what I currently have:

#### Current Status

[image: Current Status]

Answer (score 0):

Right-click on the Contract detail cell and select "Insert Row" then "Outside Group - Above". This will add a row outside the Contract group, but within the outermost group.

Comment: Thanks Steven! I'll try it now.

Comment: Additionally, you'll then need to move the Department to the same column as the Contract and delete the current department column (but NOT the group if you are prompted). I find it is easier is to start at the detail level and work up, adding parent groups with totals.

Comment: (In response to Steven): It just seems to create a row, but the column is still there, and the column has the child group identity. I can't seem to move it over to the created row, even after following your instructions. It does do something functional with the created row, but again, if I delete the column, which I want to do, the child group disappears, even if I have created the same [Contract] detail in the row.

Comment: Alan, I am just seeing your response, as well. Thanks for the feedback. I'll work on that too and see if I can get it.

Comment: @SheaMatthewKennisher, have resolve this issue, I am having similar case.